# What is the $\sigma$-field generated by an indicator function?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to prove that $\sigma(\{I_A\})=\sigma(\{A\})=\{\phi,A,A^c,\Omega\}$.

What I don't understand is what does $\sigma(\{I_A\})$ actually mean?

Since the values of $I_A$ are either $0$ or $1$, does it mean that $\sigma(\{I_A\})=\sigma(\{{0,1}\})$?

Comment: It means the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ such that $I_A\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is measurable (with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Said differently $\sigma(I_A)$ is the set of all $I_A^{-1}\langle E\rangle$ where $E$ is a Borel set of $\mathbb R$. Since $I_A$ has values in $\{0,1\}$ you can restrict to $E=\emptyset,\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @nejimban, so is $\{I_A\}$ here $\{A,A^c\}$ or $\{\phi,A,A^c,\Omega\}$

Comment: @MrDi the latter